# Python - Parsing CSV to join multiple row with subbalances_ids to one

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, merge

Hey I'm having some issues with parsing the CSV in python using Pandas.

My file has such structure:

```
user_id, user_main_account_id, user_subbalance_id 
abc1,uuid1,toJoin1 
abc1,uuid1,toJoin2
abc2,uuid2,toJoin3
abc2,uuid2,toJoin4
```

And I need to get it to the end format that contains multiple subbalance columns one next to another like this:

```
user_id ,user_main_account_id ,user_subbalance1_id ,user_subbalance2_id 
abc1    ,uuid1                ,toJoin1             ,toJoin2             
abc2    ,uuid2                ,toJoin3             ,toJoin4
```

How can this be done easily using python and Pandas? On my attempts I ended up with duplicated rows for the same user_id which I want to avoid.

Tried to split the CSV by unique user_id + main_account_id and main_account_id + subbalance_ids
but as the result on merge I get the duplicates again.

Comment: You can achieve the desired output by using the pivot_table function in Pandas

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
df['subbalance_label'] = df.groupby(['user_id', 'user_main_account_id']).cumcount() + 1
result = (
    df.pivot_table(index=['user_id', 'user_main_account_id'], columns='subbalance_label', values='user_subbalance_id', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
)
result.columns = [f'user_subbalance{i-1}_id' if i > 0 else col for i, col in enumerate(result.columns)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
  user_id user_subbalance0_id user_subbalance1_id user_subbalance2_id
0    abc1               uuid1             toJoin1             toJoin2
1    abc2               uuid2             toJoin3             toJoin4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you think about why you want to do this... but this is something that works:

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = ['user_id', 'user_main_account_id', 'user_subbalance_id']

rows = [
    ['abc1', 'uuid1', 'toJoin1'],
    ['abc1', 'uuid1', 'toJoin2'],
    ['abc2', 'uuid2', 'toJoin3'],
    ['abc2', 'uuid2', 'toJoin4']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

# store all matching user_id and main_account as list
df = df.groupby(
    ['user_id', 'user_main_account_id']
)['user_subbalance_id'].agg(list).reset_index()

# how many new columns you will need
num_new_columns = df['user_subbalance_id'].apply(len).max()

# names of new columns
new_columns = [
    f'user_subbalance{i+1}_id' for i in range(num_new_columns)
]

# ensure all lists match number of next columns
df['user_subbalance_id'] = df['user_subbalance_id'].apply(
    lambda x: x + [None] * (num_new_columns-len(x))
)

# create new columns
df[new_columns] = pd.DataFrame(
    df.pop('user_subbalance_id').tolist(), 
    index=df.index
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

final_df = df.pivot_table(index=['user_id', 'user_main_account_id'],
                      columns=df.groupby(['user_id', 'user_main_account_id']).cumcount() + 1,
                      values='user_subbalance_id',
                      aggfunc='first').reset_index()

final_df.columns = ['user_id', 'user_main_account_id'] + 
[f'user_subbalance{i}_id' for i in range(1, len(final_df.columns)-1)]
print(final_df)
final_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use Pandas, or just don't want to, you can accomplish this with Python's csv module and a simple intermediate dict that aggregates the other columns under a user_id, like:

```py
users = {
    "abc1": {
        "main_id": "uuid1",
        "sub_ids": ["toJoin1 ", "toJoin2"],
    },
    "abc2": {
        "main_id": "uuid2",
        "sub_ids": ["toJoin3", "toJoin4"],
    },
    "abc3": {
        "main_id": "uuid3",
        "sub_ids": ["toJoin5"],
    },
    "abc4": {
        "main_id": "uuid4",
        "sub_ids": ["toJoin6", "toJoin7", "toJoin8"],
    },
}
```

You can read the input and fill that structure like:

```py
import csv

users = {}
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        uid = row[0]
        data = users.get(uid, {"main_id": "", "sub_ids": []})
        data["main_id"] = row[1]
        data["sub_ids"].append(row[2])

        users[uid] = data
```

You'll need to compute the max number of sub balance columns to make:

```py
max_subids = max([len(data["sub_ids"]) for data in users.values()])
subid_cols = [f"user_subbalance{i}_id" for i in range(1, max_subids + 1)]
```

Then loop over users writing each to its own row, being sure to pad short rows with emtpy spaces to fill all the sub-balance columns:

```py
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header[:2] + subid_cols)

    for uid, data in users.items():
        row = [uid, data["main_id"], *data["sub_ids"]]
        # Pad row with empty strings to fill all columns (for proper CSV)
        row += [""] * (max_subids - len(data["sub_ids"]))

        writer.writerow(row)
```

```
| user_id | user_main_account_id | user_subbalance1_id | user_subbalance2_id | user_subbalance3_id |
|---------|----------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| abc1    | uuid1                | toJoin1             | toJoin2             |                     |
| abc2    | uuid2                | toJoin3             | toJoin4             |                     |
| abc3    | uuid3                | toJoin5             |                     |                     |
| abc4    | uuid4                | toJoin6             | toJoin7             | toJoin8             |
```

Using a TypedDict makes this easier for me in my IDE, with the autocompletes/suggestions, and errors:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class UserData(TypedDict):
    main_id: str
    sub_ids: list[str]


users: dict[str, UserData] = {}
```

Everything else stays the same.